# JS: Resizing canvas + redrawing elements on canvas

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, canvas, resize

My question: What's the best way to resize the canvas with all its drawn elements?

I have 2 examples where I tried to archieve this.

The first one works, but lacks functionality because if I would add many more elements to be drawn it would get very messy. In my second example I tried to put everything into an array and loop through it but it doesn't resize correctly anymore because it doesn't recalculate the x,y width and height anymore. Basically I wish to know a way to not have to call a function which calculates the elements x,y,width and height again before drawing. I want to to put the math into the array and when it's getting drawn,
it recalculates so I just have to make sure the canvas.width/height is updated, how do I do that?

**1st example**

```js
class Canvas {
    constructor() {
        this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
        this.resize();
    }
    
    initAreas() {
        this.firstArea = { "x": 0, "y": 0, "w": this.canvas.width, "h": this.canvas.height / 2 }
        this.secondArea = { "x": 0, "y": this.firstArea.h, "w": this.canvas.width, "h": this.canvas.height / 2 }
    }
    
    resize() {
        this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        this.initAreas();
        this.ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        this.ctx.fillRect(this.firstArea.x, this.firstArea.y, this.firstArea.w, this.firstArea.h);
        this.ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        this.ctx.fillRect(this.secondArea.x, this.secondArea.y, this.secondArea.w, this.secondArea.h);
    }

}

const canvas = new Canvas();

window.onresize = function() { canvas.resize(); }
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

canvas {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**2nd example**

```
class Canvas {
constructor() {
    this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
    this.areasToDraw = [];
    this.initAreas();
    this.resize();
}

initAreas() {
    this.firstArea = { "x": 0, "y": 0, "w": this.canvas.width, "h": this.canvas.height / 2, "color": "green" }
    this.areasToDraw.push(this.firstArea);
    this.secondArea = { "x": 0, "y": this.firstArea.h, "w": this.canvas.width, "h": this.canvas.height / 2, "color": "red" }
    this.areasToDraw.push(this.secondArea);
}

resize() {
    this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    for(this.areas in this.areasToDraw) {
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.areasToDraw[this.areas].color;
        this.ctx.fillRect(this.areasToDraw[this.areas].x, this.areasToDraw[this.areas].y, this.areasToDraw[this.areas].w, this.areasToDraw[this.areas].h);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Observation 1**: "*Since resize events can fire at a high rate, the event handler shouldn't execute computationally expensive operations such as DOM modifications. Instead, it is recommended to throttle the event using requestAnimationFrame, setTimeout or customEvent*"
This is from [MDN resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize)

**Observation 2**: on resize you need to bind the canvas, otherwise you will get canvas undefined.

**Observation 3**: when you resize the canvas, you need to empty the array of elements: `this.areasToDraw` in this case, and repopulate the array with new elements.

This is how I would do it:

```js
class Canvas {
constructor() {
    this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
    this.areasToDraw = [];
    //this.initAreas();
    //this.resize();
   
}

initAreas() {
    this.firstArea = { "x": 0, "y": 0, "w": this.canvas.width, "h": this.canvas.height / 2, "color": "green" }
    this.areasToDraw.push(this.firstArea);
    this.secondArea = { "x": 0, "y": this.firstArea.h, "w": this.canvas.width, "h": this.canvas.height / 2, "color": "red" }
    this.areasToDraw.push(this.secondArea);
}

resize() {
    this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    // empty the array
    this.areasToDraw.length = 0;
    // repopulate the array
    this.initAreas();
    for(this.areas in this.areasToDraw) {
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.areasToDraw[this.areas].color;
        this.ctx.fillRect(this.areasToDraw[this.areas].x, this.areasToDraw[this.areas].y, this.areasToDraw[this.areas].w, this.areasToDraw[this.areas].h);
    }
}

}

let canvas = new Canvas()

setTimeout(function() {
  canvas.resize()
  addEventListener('resize', canvas.resize.bind(canvas), false);
}, 15);
```

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

canvas {
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was exactly what I was looking for.